# Android WebView not loading Mixed Content

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to make a app with WebView, but the website is using `https`, but the content (ex. mp3 file) uses `http`, so Android Lollipop won't load it because it is "Mixed Content". I tried to use `onReceivedSslError` `handler.proceed();`, but it doesn't load anything. Is there a way to fix it? or could I just make all websites loaded use `http`, so It doesn't show any errors?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Since Pie (API 29), all non-HTTPS traffic in app is now disabled by default](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic).

**If you're targeting API level 26 or above**, you must first enable it in the manifest file. Add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

into `<application>` tag.

---

[Since Lollipop (API 21), WebView blocks all mixed content by default](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMixedContentMode(int)).

To change this behaviour, **when you are targeting API level 21 or above**, use:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

> In this mode, the WebView will attempt to be compatible with the
>   approach of a modern web browser with regard to mixed content. Some
>   insecure content may be allowed to be loaded by a secure origin and
>   other types of content will be blocked. The types of content are
>   allowed or blocked may change release to release and are not
>   explicitly defined.

In practice this should allow loading of images, videos, music etc. - all content that has low probability of being major security threat, when tampered/replaced by malicious third-party.

---

Alternatively use **(strongly discouraged)**:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

> In this mode, the WebView will allow a secure origin to load content
>   from any other origin, even if that origin is insecure. This is the
>   least secure mode of operation for the WebView, and where possible
>   apps should not set this mode.

Comment: I am running into the same problem.  I am targeting a device that is api19 and the above code only works on api 21, Seem to be in the sweet spot where it just doesnt work either way.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and this solution doesn't seem to work. Any new ideas?

Comment: This should not be accepted answer. It doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Hmm, does not work on API 28 for me. Tested 27, 26, 25, these work fine.

Comment: Android 9 and higher requires `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` attribute in your `application` tag of AndroidManifest.xml additionally to the `webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);` flag.

Answer (score 9):

If your min API is less than 21 and cannot call setMixedContentMode directly, you can use reflection:

```
try {
    Method m = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setMixedContentMode", int.class);
    if ( m == null ) {
        Log.e("WebSettings", "Error getting setMixedContentMode method");
    }
    else {
        m.invoke(webView.getSettings(), 2); // 2 = MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
        Log.i("WebSettings", "Successfully set MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("WebSettings", "Error calling setMixedContentMode: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

Comment: where should this code be? how do you access webView?

Comment: @syonip It depends on how you created the WebView. You can get a reference using the findViewById() method if you're in an Activity. You can put the block of code anywhere before you loading data into it (.e.g onResume() of your Activity)

Comment: @syonip In case of Cordova apps it should be in MainActivity.java as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

In android pie in addition to setting the mixed content mode, you also need to set the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` attribute in the `AndroidManifest`.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` do:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
```

and when setting up the webview, do:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

Comment: This should be the right answer ! Thank you so much. This attribute `android:usesCleartextTraffic ` is needed in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file !

Comment: Even though the default value is true, I needed this explicitly set to true also

Answer (score 4):

to load it conditionally on API >= 21, **you don't have to use reflection**.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {   
          webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've recently migrated from Crosswalk to use the native WebView.

Had to fight with this issue for a few hours. The fix was to run clearCache() prior to setting the settings.

```
webView.clearCache(false);  // <-- DO THIS FIRST
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to manifest.xml and add the following line.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

And in Java file of webview add this code.

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this problem, just make sure you have installed the Ionic's WebView Cordova Plugin (https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview).  The easiest way is to check your package.json.

Once installed:

1. Open your config.xml file
2. Check if you have an entry for `<preference name="Scheme">`
3. If you do, check that the value is "https".
4. If you don't have it, then add this line:
   `<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />`
5. Add this line:
   `<preference name="MixedContentMode" value="0" />`

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: It seems I spoke too quickly.  This solution worked... one time; at soon as I rebuilt the app, it started to block my http requests again. :(

Answer (score 0):

For those using vanilla Cordova, you'll need to add the **onResume** function in your **MainActivity.java** and call **setMixedContent** from there as shown [here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/allow-mixed-content-on-cordova-apps-webview/).

```java
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Add the following lines to enable mixed content mode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getView(); // Change from getEngine() to getView()
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
    }
```