# Loading third party non-secure images in Cordova inAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, https

I am trying to load an image from another website in Cordova inAppBrowser and I get the following error :

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.image-site.com/image.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How to resolve this?
I precise third party website does not have HTTPS, that's why I need a solution without changing 'http' in 'https'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code here:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

Also refer to this answer as it covers this issue well and provides another less secure workaround.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32875064/7837081

Answer (score -2):

Host yourself the images or proxy them with an https page.

Comment: Hosting myself is not possible (I'm requesting an API for images depending of user entries). And about proxy them with https page... is it the only solution ?

Comment: The only other solution I  know of is to convince the owner of the other website to switch on https... (As it's cordova, you could use - for android - your own chrome build, and customize it but it's more complex than setting up a proxy.)