# Mixed Content Error when playing ads In Jwplayer sdk

Tags: android, jwplayer, mixed-content

I have an android project where I integrate the JWplayer sdk, the player is playing video well
The problem is when the player arrive to play the ads it show me this exeption :

> "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://intercept.jw//data/user/0/user/files/jwplayer/jw_core/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myXmlAdsFile'. This request has been blocked;

I tried those solution without a result:

- **turn my link to https**:
  did not work, it shows me an insecure link exeption
- [allow mixed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155634/android-webview-not-loading-mixed-content):
  I dont have a web view in the player so can not use this method

this is my code to initialize my jwplayer:

```
List<AdBreak> adSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
        AdBreak adBreak = new AdBreak.Builder()
                .tag(My Xml Link)
                .offset(time when the ads show up)
                .build();
        adSchedule.add(adBreak);

    Advertising advertising = new Advertising(AdSource.VAST, adSchedule);
    PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
            .file(videoUrl)
            .build();

    List<PlaylistItem> playlist = new ArrayList<>();
    playlist.add(playlistItem);
    config = new PlayerConfig.Builder()
            .playlist(playlist)
            .advertising(advertising)
            .build();
    jwPlayerView.setup(config);
```